# Bootstrap Modal Hide function doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap modal dialog with OK/Cancel button. I expect some work to be done after OK is clicked and then close the modal dialog. So I used JS to handle OK click.

HTML:

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="RequestModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="RequestModalLabel">Confirm to submit below request?</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_close" onclick="f_test()">OK</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JS

```
function f_test () {
      var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('RequestModal'));
      myModal.hide();
}
```

The hide function doesn't work.  I searched the stackoverflow and others but didn't get good answer.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. If you have a solution you need to post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Based on the code above, I am guessing you are using bootstrap 5. Am I correct? And, are you seeing any error in the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Create the object of the modal dialog first and then use it to hide on the f_test() method as shown below,

```
 var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('RequestModal'));
 myModal.show();

function f_test () {

   myModal.hide();
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/78n9k65L/

Comment: Yes.  It must be declared in 'global' scope', and not in 'function' scope.  The function declaration will create new instance.   Thank you.